# nth root calculation syntax

Tags: python, sympy

Reading the documentation [here](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.5/modules/mpmath/functions/powers.html), the very first entry is for `Nth` roots which is what I'm looking for.

I want to know how to take e.g. the cubed quadratic root of `3^3`.

I could not see in the documentation how to do this.

> "sqrt(x) gives the principal square root of x, x√. For positive real
>   numbers, the principal root is simply the positive square root. For
>   arbitrary complex numbers, the principal square root is defined to
>   satisfy x√=exp(log(x)/2). The function thus has a branch cut along the
>   negative half real axis.For all mpmath numbers x, calling sqrt(x) is
>   equivalent to performing x**0.5."

OK, but I still don't know how to take the `nth` root of something.

Tried `4sqrt(3**3)` which gave error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1 4sqrt(3**3) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

How can I take the 4th root of `3^3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you linked answers your question if you scroll down to the root function.  The code would be `root(3**3, 4)`.